# Remove everything but #number in brackets

Tags: python

I have a file where the lines have the form #nr = name(#nr, (#nr), different vars, and names).

I would like to only have the #nr in the brackets to get the form #nr = name(#nr, #nr)

I have tried to solve this in different ways like using regex, startswith() and lists but nothing has worked so far.

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: Code

```py
for line in f.split():

    start = line.find( '(' )
    end = line.find( ')' )
    if start != -1 and end != -1:
        line = ''.join(i for i in x if not i.startswith('#'))
    print(line)
```

Edit 2:
As example I have:

```
#304= IFCRELDEFINESBYPROPERTIES('0FZ0hKNanFNAQpJ_Iqh4zM',#42,$,$,(#142),#301);
```

Afterwards I want to have:

```
#304= IFCRELDEFINESBYPROPERTIES(#42,#142,#301);
```

Comment: It's good that you tried different ways to solve this yourself. If you post that code as a [mre] and explain what difficulty you had, someone might be able to see where you were going wrong.

Comment: Can you describe more closely the exact syntax you are looking for? regex should handle this fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using regex, though trying to do it with a single find/replace would be more complicated. Instead, you can do it in two steps:

```py
import re

def sub_func(match):
    nums = re.findall(r'#\d+', match.group(2))
    return match.group(1) + '(' + ','.join(nums) + ');'

text = "#304= IFCRELDEFINESBYPROPERTIES('0FZ0hKNanFNAQpJ_Iqh4zM',#42,$,$,(#142),#301);"
result = re.sub(r'(^[^(]+)\((.*)\);', sub_func, text)
print(result)
# '#304= IFCRELDEFINESBYPROPERTIES(#42,#142,#301);'
```

So instead of passing a string as the second argument for re.sub, we pass a function instead, where we can process the results of the match with some more regex and reformatting the results before passing it back.